# Generating PDF Report from database in C#, specifically ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reporting-services

I need to generate a high quality report based on information in a SQL Server database, and I want very explicit control of the layout and appearance from inside C#.

I have several choices that I know of that are already being used for various other reports at our company:

1) SQL Server's built in Reporting Services

2) Adobe Forms

3) Crystal Reports

This information I need as PDF directly parallels what is already being displayed in the user's web browser as HTML, so creating a print stylesheet and converting the browser body to PDF is an option as well.

So this creates option 4:

4) JavaScript convert HTML to PDF (my preference at this time)

Does anybody have a recommendation as to which approach I should take, or even better an alternative? All the choices seem pretty horrible.

Comment: What does scary you in MS Reporting Service? It,s pretty awesome. I personally would definitely prefer it to CrystalReports.

Comment: Of those four: SQL Server Reporting Services - hands down. By far the best of those options, in my opinion.

Comment: There is also a tutorial out there [Output SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Report as PDF from URL with VB.NET or C#.NET](http://www.jensbits.com/2012/01/23/output-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-report-as-pdf-from-url-with-vb-net-or-c-net/) that may help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) with very good results. It is an open-source .NET port of a java library. It works really well for [creating PDFs](http://support.itextpdf.com/forum/28) *from scratch*. Remember that *editing* PDFs will always be hacky with *any* library, because PDF is an *output* format, *not* a read-write format.

Provided your HTML is fairly clean (remove javascript postbacks, anchors, ...),the  iText `HtmlWorker` can convert HTML to PDF, if you prefer that route.

[HTML to PDF in using iTextSharp](http://hamang.net/2008/08/14/html-to-pdf-in-net/):

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(doc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
```

Also [here](http://javaxtendsolutions.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/itext-1-5-html-to-pdf/).

Answer (score 2):

Use SSRS, it has a built in PDF rendering mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have used two other PDF report libraries with great success; [Active Reports](http://www.datadynamics.com/) and [Telerik Reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx). Personally I prefer the latter when it comes to programmatic control of layout and such.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look also at the DevExpress Reporting (non-free 3rd party tool):

[Overview](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Index/Reporting.xml)

[Online Demos](http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraReportsDemos/)

[Documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2162)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use the best tools to get the best solution. The best tool in this case probably is SSRS.

But that's just looking at the capabilities of the tool.
Don't forget to look at your own capabilities!

My story: I know SQL, I know C#. (Both intermediate, I'm not a guru.)
Then I lay my hands on SSRS. And burnt them, once, twice, etc. 
At the end, there was a nice result. So burning your fingers is not a wrong thing to do.
But first try to pull your html through an html to pdf converter (demo version) and see if the result it serves your needs.

Currently I'm using both:

- SSRS for creating invoices, because amounts have to be transported from one page to the next

  - [Winnovative](http://www.winnovative-software.com/) to generate documents that only need page numbers

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using .Net ReportViewer control in local mode (no report server required). It works in both webforms and winforms. You create a client-side report (.rdlc) file (which contains all the visuals as well as placement of data fields), link it up to the ReportViewer, and supply the data (DataTable or collection of objects, as long as the fields match, it doesn't matter). In client mode it supports exporting to pdf and excel (and Word too? don't remember). By default these done by a dropdown in the control itself however you can programmatically export to any of the supported formats as well. You'll end up with a byte array you can shove into a file stream.

Basically you get most of the good parts of SSRS without all of that backend complexity. There should be a ReportViewer folder in %programFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer - but versions exist for 2005 and 2008 as well. Check out http://gotreportviewer.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the 4th option is the best. In this case you don't need to change either layout of the HTML page or a layout of PDF, if one of them has been changed.
It is also more convenient making a nice design via HTML than programmatically via C# :)

Take a look at [WebToPDF.NET](http://www.tallcomponents.com/webtopdf2-features.aspx) which is a .NET component written in C# that converts HTML to PDF. The converter supports HTML 4.01, XHTML 1.0, XHTML 1.1 and CSS 2.1 including page breaks, forms and links. It passes all W3C tests (except BIDI).

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Fast Report](https://www.fast-report.com/en/product/fast-report-net/) it's good tool and i has a free version